# Setting multiple cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set multiple cookies in document.cookie, but unfortunately my code shows the cookie value as null and undefined. My code is as belows:

```
<script>
function set_cookie ( name, value, exp_y, exp_m, exp_d, path, domain, secure )
{
  var cookie_string = name + "=" + escape ( value );

  if ( exp_y )
  {
    var expires = new Date ( exp_y, exp_m, exp_d );
    cookie_string += "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString();
  }

  if ( path )
        cookie_string += "; path=" + escape ( path );

  if ( domain )
        cookie_string += "; domain=" + escape ( domain );

  if ( secure )
        cookie_string += "; secure";

  document.cookie = cookie_string;
}
</script>
<script>

alert(setCookie( "username", "Miron" ));
alert(setCookie( "username", "Mirion", 2003, 01, 15 ));
alert(setCookie("username", "John Smith", 2003, 01, 15, "","elated.com", "secure"))
</script>
```

I technically see no fault in the code. Please tell me where I had gone wrong

Comment: Your `setCookie` does not return a value so you can not call it in `alert`

Comment: your function is set_cookie not setCookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to `return` the string to `display in alert` and change your function name `set_cookie` to `setCookie`.

```
 <script>
function setCookie ( name, value, exp_y, exp_m, exp_d, path, domain, secure )
{
  var cookie_string = name + "=" + escape ( value );

  if ( exp_y )
  {
    var expires = new Date ( exp_y, exp_m, exp_d );
    cookie_string += "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString();
  }

  if ( path )
        cookie_string += "; path=" + escape ( path );

  if ( domain )
        cookie_string += "; domain=" + escape ( domain );

  if ( secure )
        cookie_string += "; secure";

  document.cookie = cookie_string;
  return cookie_string;//or document.cookie 
}
</script>


 <script>

alert(setCookie( "username", "Miron" ));
alert(setCookie( "username", "Mirion", 2003, 01, 15 ));
alert(setCookie("username", "John Smith", 2003, 01, 15, "","elated.com", "secure"))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call `setCookie`, but the method you have defined is called `set_cookie`.  If you add a `dubugger` line in you method and run it - are you hitting the debug statement?  To correct, either change the function name to `setCookie` or change the calls to `set_cookie`.

Also, the function doesn't seem to return anything, so your alerts will be `undefined` (when it does run). Once you have made the call to your `setCookie` method, just try a document.cookie in the console and you should see that your values have been set.